# Minimize chi square fot non-linear fit

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, parameters

I recently started using Mathematica, so I have a question.
I would like to find the parameters of a non-linear function by minimizing the chi square. How could I do?
The function would be like this :

y(x) =[A /(sqrt( (B^2 + 2C^2 - x^2)^2 +4C^2*x^2)] + D

Comment: Have you seen `NonlinearModelFit[]` already?

Comment: While you haven't (yet?) given any *Mathematica* code, as a new user you might not know that you should avoid starting variable names with capital letters.  For example `D` is reserved for the derivative function.  Also, is there a reason for wanting to minimize a chisquare statistic rather then performing least squares or maximum likelihood?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I know I can't use large letters to define functions. I only did it to better visualize the function. I could use maximum likelihood  but I saw that with Mathematica I can use it only with defined probability functions. How can I use the function I defined above?